# Cross-validation for time-series data: Convert user-defined list of tuples with inner lists of lists to list of tuples for applying in GridSearchCV

Tags: python, list, time-series, tuples, cross-validation

I have time series data and want to do walk forward cross-validation for my ML model in Python. To create splits I have done following:

```
cv_split = [(list_of_lists[:i], list_of_lists[i:i+1]) for i in range(1, len(list_of_lists))]
```

(where the `list_of_lists` is e.g.:`[[0,1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7,8,], ...]`
where each list stand for observations in a particular year.

The result for `cv_split` is the list of tuples with inner list of lists, each tuple is: `([[0,1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6,7,8]])`,
and this is the problem because GridSearchCV does not accept this.

I know that the following form for my `cv_split` will work:
`([0,1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]) (list of tuples of lists)`.
Well I struggle how to come from `([[0,1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6,7,8]])` to `([0,1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8])`?

Here more comprehensive:

Now I have:

```
[([[0,1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6,7,8]]) 

([[0,1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7,8]],[[9,10]])

([[0,1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10]],[[11,12,13]]) 

([[0,1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10],[11,12,13]],[[14,15,16]])]
```

And I need the following form:

```
[([0,1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]) 

([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[9,10]) 

([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13]) 

([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13],[14,15,16])]
```

I am new to Python and will be happy about any help with some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use a nested list comprehension:

```
lst = ([[0,1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6,7,8]])

t = tuple([[a for b in l for a in b] for l in lst])

print(t)
```

Output:

```
([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8])
```

UPDATE:

```
lst = [([[0,1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6,7,8]]),
       ([[0,1,2],[3,4],   [5,6,7,8]],[[9,10]]),
       ([[0,1,2],[3,4],   [5,6,7,8],  [9,10]],[[11,12,13]]),
       ([[0,1,2],[3,4],   [5,6,7,8],  [9,10],  [11,12,13]],[[14,15,16]])]

ls = [tuple([[a for b in l for a in b] for l in tt]) for tt in lst]
```

Comment: thanks for your responce! I guess, I did not precisely exspress my problem. Here is a more comprehensive example:

Comment: Now I have:   

[([[0,1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6,7,8]])
([[0,1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7,8]],[[9,10]])
([[0,1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10]],[[11,12,13]])
([[0,1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10],[11,12,13]],[[14,15,16]])]

And I need the following form:

[([0,1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8])
([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[9,10])
([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13])
([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13],[14,15,16])]


Do you maybe have some solutions for this? Thanks again!